# HP Windows 7 Laptop has limited connection to wi-fi

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

Other laptops in the house are on wi-fi, but this one cannot get a proper internet connection. It's an HP running Windows 7.

I have tried many solutions I have seen online, such as:

1. Gone into connection properties and ensured IPv4 and IPv6 were enabled, with IP address and DNS server address set to be obtained automatically.
2. Scanned with Malwarebytes
3. Ipconfig /release and /renew
4. a "netsh winsock reset"
5. Using an ethernet cable directly to the router
6. Checking for a ZeroAccess RootKit

I haven't tried anything with the drivers, but I don't know anything about how to update those. I also was unable to do a system restore for some reason. Is it possible that updating to Windows 10 would solve the issue?

Any help would be appreciated. Here is what I get from doing an ipconfig on the command line.

http://imgur.com/a/PTnjn

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem with a Dell laptop. The only thing that would work was to assign a fixed IP address and DNS to this machine. Try it with yours. Use OpenDNS at 208.67.222.222 or Google DNS  at  8.8.8.8

Comment: I did end up trying this with no luck. I set the IP address (10.0.0.222), subnet mask (255.255.255.0) and default gateway (10.0.0.1). I can confirm that that IP is in the range of what works for my other devices.

Comment: So you're saying that the other computers are in the 10.0.0.XXX IP range and they do connect to the internet ? Is this thru a wired connection or wireless? If it is wireless, have you tried wired? Trying to figure if this is a hadware , software or network problem.

Comment: Yes, other computers connect wirelessly, but also wired.

Answer (score 0):

the address assigned to your adapter "169.254...." is what is known as an auto-config address, and that's what will happen if the adapter is set to get address automatically, and doesn't get any response from a DHCP server.

If your other machines are getting IPs OK, and are set to get an IP automatically, then that means a DHCP server is running, so then the question is why isn't it assigning an IP to this laptop.

I would check the DHCP settings, which are most likely in your router.  You may have reached the number of leases it will assign.

Setting a manual IP address in the same subnet as the other Wifi adapters on the other computers should work.